# C# WebClient Downloading Wordpress Latest Zip As Homepage HTML

Tags: c#, html, wordpress, download

Can someone please tell why, when I use WebClient in C# to download a zip file, it works, unless i am trying to download http://wordpress.org/latest.zip

The zip file downloads, but when viewed with Notepad++ I can clearly see the HTML for the wordpress.org home page.

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: Please show the code you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem. Here's a simple program which works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFile("http://wordpress.org/latest.zip",
                            "latest.zip");
    }
}
```

After running that, I can open `latest.zip` with no problems. I suspect you're not *really* downloading that URL...

Comment: how large is the file you downloaded?

Comment: i just realised i had a www. in my url and it didn't like it.